# Swiper/vue stops autoplay when i drag slide my self with mouse and not resuming

Tags: vuejs3, swiper.js

I am using swiperjs on vue3 project

```
 <swiper
        class="mySwiper h-full w-full"
        :modules="modules"
        :autoplay="{delay:1000}"
        @swiper="onSwiper"
        :slides-per-view="slidesPerViewIs"
        :space-between="spaceBetween"
        @slideChange="onSlideChange"
        :pagination="{ clickable: true }"
        navigation
        :scrollbar="{ draggable: true }"
      >
        <slot></slot>
      </swiper>
```

auto play works but when i click on navigation dots or move sllider with mouse autoplay stops working

i tried autoplay start() method when slide changes but not work i think there will be much better way to avoid autoplay stopping

```
setup() {
    
    const onSlideChange = (swiper) => {
      swiper.autoplay.start()
    }
```